# chain of inequality with absolute value

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

what's wrong with my below solution:

solve |x-1| < |x| / 2

1. |x - 1| < |x| / 2
2. |x| - 1 < |x| / 2, because |x| - 1 <= |x - 1|
3. 2|x| - 2 < |x|
4. |x| < 2
5. -2 < x < 2

But the inequality doesn't hold when x = 1/2
I suspect something is wrong in step 2 but if a>b and b>=c then a>c. I can't tell what the issue is.

Comment: You correctly proved a one-way implication. If 1 is true, then 5 is true. There is no reason whatsoever to expect the converse to hold, and in fact it is not true for the reason you mentioned (more conceptually, the reverse triangle inequality doesn’t give you an if and only if statement). In other words, you made a correct bunch of statements, you just didn’t answer the question.

Comment: One way to get the full set of values of $x$ is to square both sides of your original inequality (make sure you know why this gives an equivalent inequality)

Comment: Are you saying $\left|x-1\right|<\frac{\left|x\right|}{2}$ is equivalent to $\left|x\right|-1<\frac{\left|x\right|}{2}$? Because that's false.